# Shortest self-analyzing program

Tags: code-golf

*Oh, `<PROGRAM NAME HERE>`, tell me how many character '`<CHARACTER HERE>`'/s are there in your body.*

---

I do not think it a dupe to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50980/character-counts-in-source-code). That question asks for printing a list directly but this one requires some input that will cause problem.

Your work is to write a quine-like program/function that takes an input of one character, and respond with a number telling how many times that character occurs in your program. Comments, indents, trailing spaces, line feeds all count.

The range of acceptable input **MUST** cover all characters the language you are using can accept (not as string literals or comments) and all characters with lesser index in Unicode. For exmaple, Javascript and Python 3 accept Unicode characters for variable name, then it **MUST** allow Unicode input. For some stack processing languages, there are characters like `‘Ȯß`, so part of the non-ASCII input **MUST** also be acceptable.

For example, if your program is in pure ASCII and only LF

```
foo(bar,baz)#there is a space-> 
    do things
```

The inputs and outputs should be:

- \n -> 1
- \r -> 0
- \t -> 0
- -> 9
- `a` -> 4
- `b` -> 2
- `(` -> 1
- `)` -> 1
- \x01 through \x09 -> 0
- `＋`(U+FF0B) -> undefined behaviour (you can even destroy everything or delete the program itself furiously)

The program with least characters wins.

Comment: [closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50980/character-counts-in-source-code)

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't think it's quite a duplicate, it has a difference and that could affect answers greatly.

Comment: @Okx I can see why that would be considered a duplicate...

Comment: It's definitely a duplicate.

Comment: Well, it filters out all characters but the input in the output. Not sure if it is enough to be considered unique, though.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because I think the input taking part is different enough.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 172 chars

```
lambda a:'-mbda#l.fn()+1: \\\'i'.find(a)+1#\\\\\\\\\\\\\\((((((((())))))))))fffffffbd####lllll......nnnnnnnn+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11:::::::::::::              '''''''''''''''iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
```

Using `str.find()+1` to generate 0 for any character not in program.
Using comment for complement.