# Source Code Byte Frequency

Tags: code-golf, self-referential

## Source Code Byte Frequency

---

Write a program that get a single byte character as an input and prints the frequency of that byte in the program's source code as an output.

**Examples:**

Assuming my program is: `ab#cd%b` then the output of the program should be (each line is a separate execution):

```
input         output
-----         ------
  a           0.1428571428571429
  b           28.57%
  #           14.2857143%
  c           1/7
  B           0
```

---

#### Rules:

- The format of the proportion does not need to be consistent across all inputs, e.g. a fraction for one, decimal for another, percent for a third, plain zero for non-existent byte, etc...
- If a proportion is represented as decimal, the result must be accurate to at least 4 decimal places.
- Source code should be at least 1 byte long.

---

#### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) - the shortest code (≥1) wins.

---

(It would also be fun to get the shortest code in every language, so don't hesitate to post multiple entries)

Comment: I assume characters not in the source code will not be given as input?

Comment: Actually they can be given as an input, with output of 0. I'll edit the examples with such a case, thank you.

Comment: Are we allowed to read the code itself instead of doing a quine-like thing?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205163/counting-characters)

Comment: @PkmnQ I'm not sure I got the question right.. If you meant get the source code as an argument for the program, then the answer is going to be no, unfortunately. The only input is a byte.

Comment: I don't mean from input, I mean the code reads itself. (Not what the current 2 answers are doing, they're doing a quine-like thing)

Comment: Also, is it ok if the input is `"byte"` instead of just `byte`?

Comment: About the first question, I think it should be okay. Any approach is accepted as long as you're following those two rules. About the input, you can call/execute the program in any way you want, but the input to the program must be a single byte, both of the answers given until now are okay.

Comment: Is it allowed if the program can only handle input in some subset (printable ASCII, ASCII, ANSI, UTF8 without surrogate and < 0x10000) and the whole program source code is inside that range?

Comment: What about the subset "all the characters that appears in the code"? (obviously cheating. That subset is not "defined after the challenge". But that would usually allow the program to just print a constant, such as `print 1/9`)

Comment: @PkmnQ The current consensus is that you can't (self-referential tag description: "Since this is a subset of the [quine] tag, many of the same restrictions apply, such as not reading your own source code.")

Comment: @user202729 @SomoKRoceS @caird coinheringaahing  It is correct that the ```self-referential``` tag precludes reading the source code, BUT this tag was added **after** the OP had already clarified that this was Ok, and **after**  answers that already used that approach.

Comment: @user202729 The program must handle every byte < 0x10000 as an input, no subsets.

Comment: I feel like this would also be a good code-bowling question

Comment: Does the proportion format need to be consistent? Your example seems to suggest that it is legal to use a fraction for one type of character, a decimal for one, and a percentage for another.

Comment: @beefster that's an interesting question. In my example I gave different options for formatting one can use. But I think it should be allowed to output different formats for different bytes input within the same program, as long as the value is correct and follows both of the rules.

Comment: @SomoKRoceS Except surrogate pairs?

Comment: Can fractions be simplified?

Comment: @user202729 no surrogate pairs expected. If there is a 2 bytes character, each byte of that character considered as occurance of that byte as is.

Comment: @beefster yes. Even preferred.

Answer (score 34):

## JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes

All used characters appear exactly twice. Therefore, this returns either `0` or 2/40 = `0.05`.

```javascript
F=_=>(F+'+./02>cdeilnsu').includes(_)/20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBDoIwEIXhvaeYFbSpFqwLF1g2JFzAAxAyFCypU9OCG@PZa@Pu5f@St47vMWKwr@1EfjIp9XrQLetFKWRVqxYnYx3FveTSErp9MpENvFJ1mn1gBBouqgGCG5zVNQ8hOHwOAJjlvgVLi5yDf3aPMXT5nxFvsvYMORQFoKfonZHOLwyP/5z9m34)

Answer (score 33):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 1 byte

```
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w3/D/fwMuQy4jAA) Link includes... test cases? But there's not much to test really. The program counts the number of `1`s in the input, so if the input is `1`, then this is 100% of the program's code, and the program outputs `1` accordingly, otherwise the input character is not in the program's code, and therefore the output is `0`.

Comment: would any one-character retina program work?

Comment: @golf69 Anything except a newline or a pilcrow, I guess. (A newline is a cat program and a pilcrow counts newlines, not pilcrows.)

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <sup><s>52</s></sup> 50 bytes

```python
s="print`'s=;exec s'+s`.count(input())/50.";exec s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWqaAoM68kQb3Y1jq1IjVZoVhduzhBLzm/NK9EIzOvoLREQ1NT39RATwkq/f@/erE6AA)

---

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 53 bytes

```python
exec(s:="print(('exec(s:=%r)'%s).count(input())/53)")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVmj2MpWqaAoM69EQ0MdJqBapKmuWqypl5xfChTPzCsoLdHQ1NQ3NdZU0vz/vwAA)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
s="print(('s=%r;exec(s)'%s).count(input())/55)";exec(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9hWqaAoM69EQ0O92Fa1yDq1IjVZo1hTXbVYUy85vxQokZlXUFqioampb2qqqQSTB2oEAA)

Comment: What is wrong with static data? @RahulVerma

Comment: Okay, I think I was wrong about this site @golf69. So, I'd also did the same in mine.

Comment: What is "pre-release" about Python 3.8?

Comment: @lights0123 It's an artefact of TIO - when 3.8 was added to the site it was in pre-release. The site hasn't been updated with a more accurate name yet.

Answer (score 9):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
èè
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=6Og&input=Iugi)

### Explanation

Counts number of times `è` occurs in the input. So outputs 1 if input is `è` otherwise 0

Comment: Goddamnit! I completely overthought this one! And I've used that exact trick in other, similar challenges!

Answer (score 9):

## [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary), <s>~9.84e57</s> ... <s>~3.58e42</s> 59,599,717,533,291,089,242,285,960,261,852 (~5.96e31) bytes thanks to Jo King!

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...why in the world have you scrolled this far? It's Unary - it's just going to be zeroes forever...
```

Outputs `1` if the input is `0`, `0` otherwise.

---

### brainf*** code (35 bytes)

```
-[>+>+<<-----],+++[->-<]>[>-<,]>--.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pO207bxkYXBGJ1tLW1o3XtdG1i7aKBpE6sna6u3v//hgA)

Comment: For a solid quarter of a second there I was _really_ impressed with how well my browser was handling that code block.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use the word "thought".

Comment: You can do more efficient constant generation with generating 3. [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pO207bxkYXBGJ1onXtdG1i7aKBpE6sna6u3v//xgA)

Comment: Well, the code relies on wrapping eight bit cells and EOF as zero (that last one might be what's stopping you). First, decrement to get to 255, then loop by subtracting five each time, which is 255/5=51='3'. Subtract input from this as usual, then if the input was not `3`, then subtract one from the output cell and reset this cell using `,`, which in this case acts like `[-]`. Finally subtract 2 from the output cell to get it from `3`/`2` to `1`/`0` and print

Comment: Oh, hmm. I forgot that Unary only uses `0` (mixed it up with [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage)). In that case it would be [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pO207bxkYXBGJ1tLW1o3XtdG1i7aKBpE6sna6u3v//hgA)

Answer (score 8):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 5 bytes

```
5○Qc/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/00fTuwGT9//@BNAA)

### Explanation

```
 ○    Push the byte of input
  Qc  Count how many times it's in the source code
5   / And divide by five
```

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (Node.js),  <s>61</s>  34 bytes

-16 bytes thanks to *MatthewJensen*

-11 bytes thanks to *Arnauld*

```javascript
f=c=>--('f='+f).split(c).length/34
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcixCsMgFAXQvV8R6PCUohmS1X5JFzG@xPBQqdLft5nDPeM5/c@38E21m1y2OAa74N7GKGJHL9a2VUldBW0l5r0f87KOUHIrEq2UXbEiT1o/btfAdXACzoJjcA7ch1DOICdwz@vGHw)

Comment: Since you use `f` in your code, you have to include its definition in your byte count (by adding `f=` to the start of your code. You will also have to edit it to `s='f='+f.toString()` to retain functionality.

Comment: You can also save 6 bytes by hardcoding `s.length`.

Comment: Also, you don't need `().toFixed(4)`. The challenge only specifies that the result _must be accurate to 4 decimal places_, not that it must be truncated.

Comment: With all these changes you can reduce your answer to 34 bytes: `f=c=>--('f='+f).split(c).length/34`.

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), inspecting its own source code, 20 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
 f←{(+/÷≢)⍵=,⎕CR'f'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///XyHtUduEag1t/cPbH3Uu0nzUu9VW51HfVOcg9TT12v//0xSANBeQ1ACTCmDSQB0A)

Note the leading space in the code. When a function is defined in APL, the interpreter converts the source code to its own whitespace formatting (strips most spaces but inserts some at certain places, including the start of each line). The system functions that retrieve the source code (e.g. `⎕CR` and `⎕NR`) give the converted representation.

`f←` part cannot be removed from the score because the source inspection depends on itself being defined as `f`.

```apl
⎕CR'f'  ⍝ Get the char matrix representation of function f
,       ⍝ Convert the 1-row matrix to a vector
⍵=      ⍝ Compare each char of above with the input char
(+/÷≢)  ⍝ Compute the average
```

---

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), quine-like, 26 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
(+/÷≢)⍞=13⍴'''(+/÷≢)⍞=13⍴'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@Gtv7h7Y86F2k@6p1na2j8qHeLuro6FkGQ6v@caVzaXEBCHUQYAAA)

There is no escape sequence in APL's string literal. Instead, one single quote is represented by two single quotes, so the literal `'''(+/÷≢)⍞=13⍴'` gives the string `'(+/÷≢)⍞=13⍴`.

```apl
'...'   ⍝ Start with the string literal
13⍴     ⍝ Cycle-take first 13 chars, adding `'` at the start to the end
⍞=      ⍝ Compare with single-char input from stdin
(+/÷≢)  ⍝ Compute the average
```

Comment: Is there a special encoding where these characters are representable with 20 bytes? I’m just wondering, since the input is supposed to be a “single byte character”, isn’t it possible to write an APL program consisting of non-ASCII characters only and always writing `0` as result…

Comment: @Holger The page linked at the "bytes" text defines the single-byte character set for Dyalog APL.

Comment: Ok, that’s for the posted programs. But alternatively, what if you don’t use it. Is it possible to write a program only consisting of multi-byte characters (assuming, e.g. UTF-8) and always evaluating to zero (as for this challenge, the input always is a “single byte character” which never matches)?

Comment: @Holger There's a [2-char 6-byte Unicode-only program that prints 0](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@jzkWPeteA2P/TAA), but I don't think it fulfills the task because the source code actually contains 6 bytes `e2 89 a2 e2 8d ac` and the task is to "print the frequency of that *byte*".

Comment: That’s great. Well, the OP has to tell whether we can take “single byte character as an input” literally…

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>26</s> 23 bytes

-3 bytes by using the shortest standard quine in 05AB1E.

```
0"D34çýI¢23/"D34çýI¢23/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7PQ8tMjLWR@X9/w8A)

### Explanation

```
0                       Push a 0 for double quote insertion later.
 "D34çýI¢23/"           Push the quine string.
             D          Duplicate the quine string.
              34çý      Insert a double quote between rach item on the stack.
                  I¢    Count how many times the input appeaes
                    23/ And divide by 23.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, <sup><s>56...38</s></sup> 36 bytes (without reading own source code)

```ruby
p~%r,[+-2\[-\]p~%r+2?./8:],?1.0/18:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcq7CsIwAEDR/f6FSKe8o0LIEl9/kXQRVARpS9TBpZ9u1PHAqa/Tu7Vp7qrMQvmSVen/Ej5pE2Ivk9PWuBDtbzHTUZFkBApPoSehMQQiDsuOPQeOnLlwZcWaDQu2LD/j9LyNw6Op4f4F)

Each of the 18 distinct characters in the code appears twice. The input is tested against a comma-delimited regexp. The outer `[]` is a character class containing literal characters plus two character ranges: `+-2` is equivalent to the literal characters `+,-./012` and `\[-\]` is equivalent to the literal characters `[\]`. The code prints `0.05555555555555555` (decimal expansion of `1.0/18`) if the regexp matches the input character; `0` is printed otherwise.

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 27 bytes (reads own source code)

```ruby
p (IO.read($0).count$_)/27r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckrEoAgAEDB/k5hIEAQHYvZTyF5BMf/WMBBCF5eNO6sj/OT0pVJM2i/TasUpdKLizaIURVV7f/EMKDxbEysSASKBUfEEn6NNLR09Owcr7vC6eydcvsB)

Reads its own source and counts occurrences of the input. Output is a rational number.

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl` + [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), 24 bytes (reads own source code)

```ruby
p`cat #$0`.count($_)/24r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxDoMgAEDR/Z/CBkxgqFpjO9fWe4gl0XQBQmHw8mLf@mL@7KUEY5dUCdmZxvrskpKzbvsh/geDZSFRIZB0NHgyDsWMpqVnIDLy4s3EysaNOw8uPKkPH9LXu1@5uhM)

Same as above but uses `cat` (from coreutils) to read the source.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>77</s> 75 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
f <-function(c)sum(c==unlist(strsplit(capture.output(dump("f","")),"")))/75
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1NC8IwDEDv/oowD7bgJ6JDcd49CeJdZmxdYbYzTRB//XQFLy6HHB7vJdRaMs@L85cYhNAUrYXdxIpHdsEr1FEeCotCfO0iq8gUm9qxwrJhITMNwo2wusmjUZnNxlmmdVp6lq/@bneChiEsB/9cJb7ucUk8HwzhVTJW8P227UmQpAUUe5hP54tlGlAYiAyyhldlPJB4uLkO1G9wHkan0Riuwl2y@SXO9yOuKMi9gvPh@O3YkC3RtB8)

Uses R `dump(,"")` function to output own source code*, capturing output (normally to the console) using `capture.output()`.  Then finds the number of matches to the function argument `c`, divided by the source code length (75 bytes).

*Note that the TIO interface gives slightly differently-formatted output from the `dump()` function to running directly in R, so counts of whitespace characters are inaccurate in TIO (but correct in R).

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) (without reading own source code), 106 bytes

```r
'->p;sum(gregexpr(scan(,""),sQuote(p),f=T)[[1]]>0)/53'->p;sum(gregexpr(scan(,""),sQuote(p),f=T)[[1]]>0)/53
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X13XrsC6uDRXI70oNT21oqBIozg5MU9DR0lJU6c4sDS/JFWjQFMnzTZEMzraMDbWzkBT39SYLE3/07i4lBXSFPKTk0uLihVKyjOTUxUy8xSK80uLgCxbOwWjw9sNDcwUbBUM9AwMLSzMzC2N/gMA)

<s>Same</s> Similar approach to above, but including quoted string instead of reading the source code itself.

Comment: [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY3BbsIwDEDvfIVVDjgSg5YJyhD9gJ0mTbujziQ0UkmKYwvt67u2RypLPjy9Z3Pv2D4uPlxSVCZb9Q7Ob04DiY8BySS9I1WVhtYnwSScutYLUt2Jst1ElU4Fr3rvMHPZOsuMmZbZlvuX26NgYAnvi1eOEz/MuE68XCzhWQs1MHw7zSSYpHyTF7uPY5kXgBSZLYmBZ2MDsAa4@hG0f@ADrL5Xa/hVGZLiOM4O0Id5Iw1HvTXw8/k1ZGLZ1WT7fw) for the `dump()` solution

Comment: Thanks again Giuseppe!

Answer (score 5):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 126 bytes

```
method(h,"mmmeeettthhhooodd((((,,,,aaaaassssMuubl  pppn34L))))iif==102/6"asMutable append(34)asList map(o,if(o==h,1,0))sum/62)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bctNCsMgEEDhqwxZKQj5JYuCN0hu0I1BRUGdoY7nt3bfb/t4EbuHl4Z3z44DWhHUlHN2zjFzCAERrRWDGsxPHe7WngRARGU/LjnE6LVel20@JzMymyc5MESuWLEf0tQrVoZsSKCKXqDWQa1qkbK2PJ@b7F5Mf08J9ImFU@lf)

Answer (score 5):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>63</s> 60 bytes

```php
fn($a)=>strstr('ffnn($a)==>>str\\\',,??11//220::',$a)?1/20:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSZvs/LU9DJVHT1q64pAiINNTT0vIgIrZ2ILGYmBh1HR17e0NDfX0jIwMrK3UdoKS9oT6QbfDfmosrNTkjX0ElDahRXVNBT0FJQcNY38xAMyZPyRohl4dHzgCPHNBynJJK6kq45ZJhcgYwuf//AQ)

Much better solution than the first version, each char is present 3 times so if it is found, results in 3/63.

EDIT: saved 3 bytes by re-using `n` as var name (I had the luck that the total count still saved the repetition of all numbers for the calculus)

EDIT2: fixed the problem that `n` wasn't counted for not being in the string, manages to keep it 60 by removing `"` and introducing `\` (thanks to Dom Hastings)

EDIT3: fixed the problem with `0` wasn't counted because it was at the end (thanks to Dominic van Essen)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't count `n` now, presumably because of the re-use... I did wonder if there was a way to use stringwise XOR to avoid having both quotes, not sure if that would help you? `f^A`  == `'`...

Comment: @DomHastings good catch! I'll try to fix this, also the second quote is here just because I cannot introduce a `'` in the string without using a `\\`, I could get rid of it maybe, it was for the first version

Comment: @DomHastings should be fixed now ;)

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##fczBCkIhEAXQvV8hIoyCTENhC18@f8RNRIMrk@r/zYhHqyfc1T3c20rrl9RKE5pj52r01cb19X6OGGCuvyau3y7nDM6l5H0IhAhuUELygfoixP1WHlLzWIGVKJU0p8OZbK5q@Vud2HjfRQVqf0iTU5yYn9hxM9qs9w8) by using ```.05``` instead of ```1/20```.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen yeah I thought about that already, but the frequency would no longer be .05 but 3/57, and then it wouldn't be 57 anymore because I'd have to have 3 times 3, 5 and 7 ;) subtle to optimize!

Comment: Doh!  You're right!  I'm an idiot!  So I guess that this strategy pauses at 'nice' fractions!

Comment: So just one more comment: you shouldn't end the string with a 'lonely' character, or the ```strstr``` approach will fail (as it [currently](https://tio.run/##JcnBCoQgEIDhu08hIYyC5GjQwdZ8ES/L0uDJpHr/2SL4T9/fa@dP7rULRYmpafU1aT2v404DUXslrY@VUsDanL13LoQYEew9s3cBI/IixParu1SkAcHIUQ5ST25GU9qwCOY/) does for the character '0'...  I think you need to swap '::' and '0' ...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen the strategy was more "die and retry" actually :D your last comment is a great catch, actually it failed on "0" because `strstr` returns from the first found substring to the end of the string, and PHP evaluates `"0"` to false (but happily `"0::"` is truthy), thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>225</s> <s>221</s> <s>217</s> <s>203</s> 197 bytes

-28 bytes ceilingcat

```c
char*t,r;main(i,s){for(i=getchar(asprintf(&t,s="char*t,r;main(i,s){for(i=getchar(asprintf(&t,s=%c%s%1$c,34,s));*t;r+=*t++==i);printf(%1$c%%d/197%1$c,r);}",34,s));*t;r+=*t++==i);printf("%d/197",r);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lctNCsJADEDhuwxOmT@RoiAScpgh2pqFVZLsxLOPbXUtuH7fo@1I1BpdqyQrArfKU@Ci8TncJTCOF1taqPoQnmwInRVF96f35NX3Gyr7w0wjJAPJmCxnRI7wpYvw/rzrT8cVS4SX@724D3erbU3f)

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
39'39m7/h'hm7/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39hS3dgy11w/Qz0DSP7/r26sDgA)

Each byte is present exactly twice in the source code. Therefore each byte has a frequency of either 1/7 or 0.

```
39       % Push code-point for '
'39m7/h' % Push literal char array
h        % Horizontally concatenate. Automatically converts to char array.
m        % Ismember: is input in this char array?
7/       % Divide by seven
```

Answer (score 5):

### x86 machine code (MS-DOS .COM format), <s>53</s> <s>49</s> 44 bytes

Edit: Saved 4 bytes by eliminating a redundant CALL/RET and 5 bytes by outputting via `INT 29H`.

Input is taken from the command line: no input will search for `NUL` (hex 00H). Result is in the form "00/00" (i.e. "03/44" for an input of ")").

The counting part is really easy since this is a COM program: I scan for the target byte starting at DS:100H until I hit the end of the program code. To print the result and total counts, I use `AAM` to convert the numbers into unpacked BCD (which will always be less than 99) and then print the digits after flipping them so that they're displayed in the correct order.

Hex dump:

```
A0 82 00 B9 2C 00 33 D2 BF 00 01 F2 AE E3 03 42 EB F9 8B C2 E8 07 00 B0 2F CD 29 B8 2C 00 D4 0A 05 30 30 86 E0 CD 29 86 E0 CD 29 C3
```

TASM source for generated code:

```
IDEAL

MODEL   TINY
CODESEG
ORG 100H

PSIZE   EQU PEND-MAIN
PLEN    EQU PSIZE+1     ; Loop needs to be one larger so we can break on CX=0

MAIN:
    MOV     AL,[0082H]  ; Get search value from the command line
    MOV     CX,PLEN
    XOR     DX,DX
    MOV     DI,100H     ; Start search from the beginning of the program
CLOOP:
    REPNZ   SCASB       ; Search for value
    JCXZ    CDONE       ; Exit when at end of string
    INC     DX
    JMP     CLOOP
CDONE:
    MOV     AX,DX
    CALL    DISPNUM
    MOV     AL,'/'
    INT     29H
    MOV     AX,PSIZE
    ; Fallthrough to print last number and exit

DISPNUM:
    AAM                 ; Convert value to unpacked BCD (AH:AL)
    ADD     AX,3030H
    XCHG    AH,AL
    INT     29H
    XCHG    AH,AL
    INT     29H
    RET

PEND:

END MAIN
ENDS
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 46 bytes

```py
print(open(__file__).read().count(input())/46)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI78gNU8jPj4tMyc1Pl5Tryg1MUVDUy85vxQol5lXUFqioampb2Km@f9/KgA)

Straightforward enough, reads its own source code, counts how many times the input character appears, and returns that divided by 46 (the length of the code). You can also do it in 42 bytes with

```py
lambda c:open(__file__).read().count(c)/42
```

but it's a little weird as this isn't a complete program (and since `__file__` will give the whole program, if you try to add a `f=` header, the frequencies get messed up).

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
c/+N"c/+NQ7"Q7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1lf208JRASaKwWa//@v7qcOAA)

### Explanation

```
c/+N"c/+NQ7"Q7
    "c/+NQ7"    # String literal
  +N            # Prepend '"'
 /          Q   # Count occurrences of the input in that string
c            7  # Divide by 7
```

Answer (score 4):

## Google Sheets, 51

Input is in B1.

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"[^"&B1&"]",))/51
```

For once, we can't use the auto-close trick because the calculation would be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 30 bytes

```
echo `tr -dc "$1"<$0|wc -c`/30
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I18hoaRIQTclWUFJxVDJRsWgpjxZQTc5Qd/Y4P///woA)

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://fishlanguage.com/), 24 bytes

```
'3d*0${:}=+40l4)?.+6*,n;
```

Assumes input on the stack.

1. Reads the code as a string literal, except for the leading `'`
2. `3d*` pushes the character code of `'`, and a counter `0` is also added.
3. Main loop `${:}=+`, increment the counter if the topmost value is equal.
4. `40l4)?.` Exit main loop if all values are read, if not jump back
5. `+6*,n;` print the result of floating point division

Comment: It doesn't actually save any bytes, but you can do [this](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X904RctApdqq1lbbxCzHRNNeT0snz1pB4f///7rFJgA) to make a couple of no-ops

Comment: @JoKing Doesn't work on fishlanguage.com. I'm not sure how your code works on tio, since you are jumping to an y of 6 in the code box.

Comment: In the reference interpreter, if the y coordinate of the pointer is above the number of lines then it is reset to zero (though `.` somewhat paradoxically throws an error for negative values)

Answer (score 3):

## [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), 49,673,539,524 bytes

This code contains `49673539524` null bytes, and can actually fit into the universe (and even on a reasonably sized hard drive [or even a flash drive!]), which is saying a lot for Lenguage! Outputs digits as characters; `␁` (with `␁` replaced with an actual Start of Heading character, ASCII `1`) for `1` and infinite null bytes (ASCII `0`) for `0`; `␀␀␀␀␀...` (with `␀` replaced with an actual null character) repeated forever. Converted to codepoints, it's pretty much `00000...` forever, or just `0`. [Try brainf*** online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9pOO1pXTzs2Vlvv/38A)*

```
,[>+[-.+]]+.  # full program
,             # set cell 0 to code point of input
 [       ]    # while cell 0 is nonzero...
  >+          # set cell 1 to 1
    [   ]     # while cell 1 is nonzero...
     -        # set cell 1 to 0
      .       # output character with code point in cell 1
       +      # set cell 1 to 1
          +   # set cell 0 to 1
           .  # output character with code point in cell 1
```

Well this ain't winning. The only reason I submitted this in the first place was because the method used is extremely simple. The code is translated using the method shown in [my other Lenguage answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218529/94066) into the brainf*** program `,[>+[-.+]]+.`.

<sub>*The reason the TIO link outputs 1 for empty input is because empty input can simulate input of a null byte in brainf***, as the current cell is set to `0` if there is no input to take.</sub>

<sub>Side note: I had ended up golfing over \$7.7×10^{40}\$ bytes from the Lenguage program (34 from the brainf*** program) since my original version. My first attempt was `-[----->+<]>-->,[<<++[------<+>]<+++.>>-[.]]<.`, my second attempt was `-[----->+<]>-->,[<---.++[.]]<.`, I realized I don't need to output the decimal point (these programs prepended decimal points), and my third attempt was `-[----->+<]>-->,[<-[.]]<.`, until I realized I could golf this down a **ton** by outputting as characters.</sub>

Comment: Nice answer! It looks like I should have used Lenguage instead of Unary myself

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
øQ¬c"øQ¬cq¹/9"q¹/9
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=%2bFGsYyL4UaxjcbkvOSJxuS85&input=Wyf4JywnUScsJ6wnLCdhJywnYicsJ2MnLCciJywncScsJ7knLCcvOSddCi1tUg)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>159</s> <s>108</s> 90 bytes

```c
x,s;main(c,v)char**v;{for(c=open(__FILE__,0);read(c,&x,1);s+=x==*v[1]);printf("%d/90",s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///v0Kn2Do3MTNPI1mnTDM5I7FIS6vMujotv0gj2Ta/IDVPIz7ezdPHNT5ex0DTuig1MQWoUK1Cx1DTuljbtsLWVqss2jBW07qgKDOvJE1DSTVF39JASadY07r2////xQA)

-51, thanks to ceilingcat (and also without the four-character-filename limitation)

-18, thanks to ceilingcat!

Comment: By source file, you mean filename, right?

Comment: I think it's allowed but you have to include the file name length in the byte count

Comment: @Sanchises Well, given that I don't use the filename for the solution, it just requires it to be that specific length (can be any name), unlike the example [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072/97663) I wouldn't count it.

Comment: @ceilingcat oh, fantastic, thanks! Didn't know about the `char**v`-declaration after the function definition, have to look that up.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 46 bytes

```
StringCount[ToString[#0, InputForm], #1]/46 &
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLCsIwEAB/ZWnAU6Aq1osIQqDQW1Fvyx6Wmj4Oycqy/f4Y8DjMMIltjYltm7jMcC8v0y0vQfZs@JY/oTt6GPJ3t140kQd3ovZyhQOUsXpD56GBxsOMvUoKKytPFjXIJ6Ijolq2D3hyXiLW1bnr6FZ@) Pure function. Takes a single-character string as input and returns a rational number as output. Note the trailing space, which is necessary for the `InputForm` string to match the function.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 98 bytes

```lua
s="s,i,p=s..'s=;load(s)(...)',-1,0while p do i,p=i+1,s:find(...,p+1,1)end print(i/98)"load(s)(...)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCoAgEAB/RbqotG1564EfE2zRgpi0RZ9veus4MMyEZ81ZfCPAkLwgavFLOFcyYg0iWg2dg@E9OGwqKTpV9bh1IPPOkaoDqaCzWySVLo634X4abfOv5DL5AA)

Ported [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209325/59169) to Lua.

The problem with Lua string functions is that you can't accept user input for anything but `string.find` with truthy fourth argument. Anyone trying to golf this should test all magic characters `^$()%.[]*+-?` as possible inputs.

Alternatively,

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 84 bytes (reads own source)

```lua
s,i,p=io.open(arg[0]):read(),-1,0while p do i,p=i+1,s:find(...,p+1,1)end print(i/84)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBCoAgEEDRq7h0aDKFFiF0kmghaDUgOmjR8U1afnj8@LjWKhLySlllDkm6cm56B1uC8xJwNKjfi2IQLHwWvxwMVntQ8lIphdzTQEhecKF0S5qWGVrffg)

This also assumes that `arg[0]` can be used as path to program, which most likely is so.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 48 bytes

```javascript
function f(c){return--(f+'').split(c).length/48}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcgxDoAgDADA3Ve4ATHg4uB3CKGIwWKguBjfXnU13nirPWx1Je6kj5kZGjqKGXuQTp3FUyuotYRBCGXqniI9b5LHQMs4zRe7jDUnb1IOEqTYhFLd5@Dn4s@V9/gG)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 54 bytes

```python
f=open(__file__).read();print(f.count(input())/len(f))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802vyA1TyM@Pi0zJzU@XlOvKDUxRUPTuqAoM69EI00vOb8USGfmFZSWaGhq6ucA1aZpagL1AQA)

`__file__` contains the path to the file the program is in. So f opens the file where it is and grabs the contents of it.
`print(f.count(input())/len(f))`

This counts the occurrences of the character provided and divides it by the total number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 18 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 14.82 bytes

```
34C"34C+sc9/"+sc9/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhabjE2clYBYuzjZUl8JTEIkoPILFjpDGAA)

Based off @Mukundan314's Pyth answer.

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
zdsc6/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLqlKKk830IRyo2IKFKRAGAA)

Probably cheating but I'll put it here anyway.

##### Explanations

```python
34C                 # Push chr(34), the double quote
   "34C+sc9/"+      # Prepend it to the string "34C+sc9/"
              sc    # Swap and count the number of times the input is in the string
                9/  # Divide by 9 (Half the length of the program)
```

```python
zd      # Push the source code
  sc    # Swap and count the number of times the input is in the string
    6/  # Divide by 6 (The length of the program)
```