# Autogrammatic pairs

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source, counting

For today's task, we have two programs, P and Q, both in the same language. Each of them receives a single-character input.

If P receives character K, P says how many times K appeared in Q. (You can use any output format for P or Q; they need not be the same, the only requirement is that your format can represent any nonnegative integer uniquely). Vice versa: If Q gets K, Q says how many times K was in P.

**Create P and Q,** which must not be identical programs. To further cement this, P and Q must be minimal (remove any amount of characters from either and it doesn't work as required).

Whoever made the combined lengths of P and Q the shortest wins (tiebreak: earlier post). Have fun!

Comment: "P and Q must not carry out what has been outlined before if a positive amount of characters is removed from either" -> is this a convoluted way to say programs have to be minimal? (maybe it's just me that finds this unclear, note that english is not my mother tongue)

Comment: English is not my native either. I just wanted to be absolutely clear and objective about what I wanted.

Comment: Adding new rules that invalidate the majority of already-posted answers seems a little unkind, to say the least.

Comment: I'll roll these back. I put one in place hoping for "less trivial" pairs; the other can stay (7 out of 11 answers given have independent versions already so the second would be way less disruptive).

Comment: How would input work for languages such as Whitespace? Inputting spaces would work, but how would you input a tab or newline (Whitespace is written with only spaces, tabs, and newlines)?

Comment: I do not know what would be the most elegant method of doing this. I surmise that you could copy-paste the tabs or NLs from another source, although if these are naturally un-inputtable due to some restriction of the language I'm not about to try to work around the restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

**P**

```
“ṾċḷḤ”Ṿċḷ“”Ḥ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/cd6X64Y/vDHUseNcyF8YASIN6OJf8Ptz9qWvP/v1JIRmaxQnFGfmlOikJ6ZlmqQqJCUmlecoZCfppCVWpRfrFCWn5OTn55aopCUqVCSXlqDlBNSTlQnLAlSgA)**

**Q**

```
“ṾċḷḤ”Ṿċḷ”“Ḥ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/cd6X64Y/vDHUseNcyF8YBMkNyOJf8Ptz9qWvP/v1JIRmaxQnFGfmlOikJ6ZlmqQqJCUmlecoZCfppCVWpRfrFCWn5OTn55aopCUqVCSXlqDlBNSTlQHI8lc0C8HUuUAA)**

P and Q are very similar, they both contain two of each of the same set of six characters. The only difference is `“”` vs `”“` (empty list vs a single open quote character).

#### How?

```
“ṾċḷḤ”Ṿċḷ..Ḥ - Link: character, C
“ṾċḷḤ”       - list of characters = ['Ṿ', 'ċ', 'ḷ', 'Ḥ']
      Ṿ      - un-evaluate Jelly code = ['“', 'Ṿ', 'ċ', 'ḷ', 'Ḥ', '”']
         ..  - either:
             -   “” - empty list = []
             -   ”“ - character literal = '“'
        ḷ    - yield the left argument of this dyadic atom (C)
       ċ     - count occurrences (of C in the un-eval list)
           Ḥ - double
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 29 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

### Mutually dependent lambdas

```apl
P←{≢⍸⍵=⎕CR'Q'}
Q←{≢⍸⍵=⎕CR'P'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@BR24TqR52LHvXueNS71fZR31TnIPVA9VquQGwSAeq1QC3qtupcgSAiQB0IgEwQGQCUBDIDQaxAECtAHQA)

`P←`… establish a function with the following definition:

`{`…`}` dfn; the argument (a character) is `⍵`:

`⎕CR'`…`'` **C**haracter **R**epresentation of the function called … (as a character matrix)

`⍵=` 2D mask indicating where the character is equal to elements of that matrix

`⍸` **ɩ**ndices where true

`≢` tally them

### Mutually independent lambdas (35 bytes)

```apl
P←{≢⍸⍵=⎕CR'P'⋄QQ}
Q←{≢⍸⍵=⎕CR'Q'⋄PP}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@BR24TqR52LHvXueNS71fZR31TnIPUA9UfdLYGBtVyB2GQDQbIBAbVAzeq26lyBICJAHQiATBAZANQPZAaCWIEgVoA6AA)

The only difference from the above is that each function reads its own source, and that each has a dummy statement containing supplemental characters that ensure that they have identical counts of all characters. `⋄` is the statement separator, but the second statement will never be reached (it'd cause a vale error anyway) because the function terminates with the value of the first non-assigning statement.

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 63 bytes

Inspired by @Wasif's awesome PowerShell answer

-6 bytes thanks to mazzy!

```powershell
$P={$Q-replace"[^$args]"|% le*}
$Q={$P-replace"[^$args]"|% le*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXAtlolULcotSAnMTlVKTpOJbEovThWqUZVISdVq5ZLJRAoH4BT/r@aSoCGepG6JpeaSqCGeqG65n8A)

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), Independent Functions, <strike>109  103  93</strike> 77 bytes

This version does not require the functions to be in the same file; they are completely independent of one another.

```powershell
$P={"Q$P"-replace"\|P|[^$args]"|% le*}
$Q={"P$Q"-replace"\|Q|[^$args]"|% le*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXAtlopUCVASbcotSAnMTlVKaYmoCY6TiWxKL04VqlGVSEnVauWSyUQqCxAJRBZWSCGsv9qKgEa6gHqmlxgRiCYEYjEAEr9BwA)

For either answer, it costs 2 bytes to make the input character case-sensitive.

Comment: Didn't know that we can omit `,''` in `-replace`, +1

Comment: smart Independent Functions - (oO)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <del>128</del> 122 bytes

```powershell
function P($x){cd Function:;(gc Q)-replace"[^$($x)]"|% le*}
function Q($x){(gc $psCommandPath)[0]-replace"[^$($x)]"|% le*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P600L7kkMz9PIUBDpUKzOjlFwQ0qYmWtkZ6sEKipW5RakJOYnKoUHacCUhOrVKOqkJOqVcsF1xsI1gtSrlJQ7Jyfm5uYlxKQWJKhGW0Qi1P7/wAN9Wx1Ta5AMPUfAA)

-6 bytes Thanks to mazzy and Zaelin Goodman

Two functions work in different ways.

`P()` will read `Q()`'s source code and count occurrences of the given character.

`Q()` will read the source of the first line in the script (Which is source of function `P()`), and count occurrences of the given character.

I Couldn't be more creative than this solution to follow the rules of the question, otherwise if I made two functions identical, I could save some bytes.

Comment: Found a shorter way to get the contents of Q, and replaced the method in Q with the shorter one from P; also, you don't need the `$()` around `$x` in the strings; all together this goes down to 111 bytes. I think, because P and Q are different letters, you could use the same method to get content in both, but I left them different because I'm unsure on that. [Try it online :)](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P600L7kkMz9PIUBDpUKzWgXGtwrULUotyElMTlWKjlOpiFXSUVKqUVXISdWq5YLrCQTrSU5RcIPpstZIT1YI0MSp93@AhnqRuiZXoIZ6obrmfwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P600L7kkMz9PIUBDpUKzWgXGtwrULUotyElMTlWKjlOpiFWqUVXISdWq5YJrCARrSE5RcINpsdZIT1YI0MSu8X@AhnqyuiZXIJj6DwA "PowerShell – Try It Online") of course :)

Comment: If you're allowed to use a scriptblock as a function, which I believe is legal, you can actually trim this down much further, to a wonderfully-accidental 69 bytes; but this also hinges on the difference in letters being enough of a difference to count - which I think the challenge is ambiguous on [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXAtlolULcotSAnMTlVKTpOJbEovThWSUdJqUZVISdVq5ZLJRCoJACfkv9qKgEa6kXqmlxqKoEa6oXqmv8B "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy thanks for that I will implement your idea soon!

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman your submission is very talented and unique, you should post a seperate answer!

Comment: @mazzy Ah, nice catch! I didn't know you could leave out the empty string on replace; that just might save some golfs I have stuck in limbo :)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), version-dependent, <s>110</s> 84 bytes

*Edit: -26 bytes with inspiration from [user81655's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220148/95126)*

*Note: Function-pairs #1 and #2 below depend on the version-dependent output formatting of [R](https://www.r-project.org/) functions, and work on my locally-installed [R](https://www.r-project.org/) version 3.2.1, but unfortunately not on version 3.5.2 which is installed on TIO.  A TIO-compliant (but longer) adjusted version of #1 can be tried here: [try it](https://tio.run/##PYzBCsIwEETv@YoBD9mFID2It/oR4g@UuC2Ctps0C/n72BZ0mMODYV5u2m8dbY7ltcygGFDRIzFW@5C8acoySdW8L3d5WhTSYS3SBcRBi2U5L1bUClXmgHE7P5hxw56OW/rLf25l6MHsnJKHZ5xwdYm8Hnhx7Qs).*

**1: functions that read each other's source code: 84 = 61+23 bytes**

```r
p=function(c,x=q)sum(el(gregexpr(c,capture.output(x),f=T))>0)
q=function(c,x=p)p(c,x)
```

**2: functions that read their own source code, but not each other's: 142 = 2x 71 bytes**

```r
p=function(c,pr=2,q=1)sum(el(gregexpr(c,capture.output(p),f=T))>pr-q-q)
q=function(c,qr=2,p=1)sum(el(gregexpr(c,capture.output(q),f=T))>qr-p-p)
```

**3: 'proper quine'-like functions that don't read their own source code: 236 = 2x 118 bytes**

```r
p=function(c,q=1,p=1)2*sum(el(gregexpr(c,sQuote('function(c,p=1,q=1)2*sum(el(gregexpr(c,sQuote(),f=T))>p-q)'),f=T))>q-p)
q=function(c,p=1,q=1)2*sum(el(gregexpr(c,sQuote('function(c,q=1,p=1)2*sum(el(gregexpr(c,sQuote(),f=T))>q-p)'),f=T))>p-q)
```

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), version-dependent, 150 bytes

*New function-pair to comply with the newly-added rule that functions cannot be anagrams of each other*

**4: functions that read their own source code, but not each other's, and are not anagrams of each other: 150 = 2x 75 bytes**

```r
p=function(z)sum(el(gregexpr(z,chartr("yz","zy",capture.output(p)),f=T))>0)
q=function(y)sum(el(gregexpr(y,chartr("zy","yz",capture.output(q)),f=T))>0)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 51 bytes

```javascript
p=(k,s='q='+q)=>s.split(k).length-1
q=k=>p(k,'p='+p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpBCoAgEEbhfRcZh1Jo12a8i0SUKfGb0vXNaOXy473TPS6vt0fRz1IrRIUpCyWhMbHYbDKiLyqwidu1l0PPQ5IgFu0jtAtccfurKCgCMQ@/UqfWYtc@1Rc)

Works assuming we're allowed to read the other program (grey area but not explicitly disallowed in the rules).

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>104 96</s> 56 bytes

```
a=`<$0` b=$1;<<<${#a//[^$b]}
```

```
b=`<$0` a=$1;<<<${#b//[^$a]}
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@G@nkKZgY6Pu6u@m/j8tv0ghWUFDpVqj2MpKU0XDRsVAs1YzWkGlOllZxbBWIbamRkNDW7tIU9PaxsZGpbpI16D2P1AnF5edQjrMFC7cphgqqyRjN4ULbEpyRm5@ioJ2hUIaV1VxBtBh6tHqUJbRfwA)
[Try it* online!](https://tio.run/##lVCxboMwEN39Fa8GyYkQITAi062VOtEhWxMJCia2FOwIQ1uF8O2paTJUmdrT6U739N7T3Z2svKQ4nzHCQ96pvdLlAcfO7LuytSnhnPtv/uiPSVZwf11MaVD4a/gxqMPSeKLFFCy8JMu8eLn7Kz129MTRJ0I8bF5ycuyU7hFqsI0UMHd7LOwSUvUoZ6AS1uKgWjcbPYtXW/36G07ByHAlhMPN2dkqC5clWlOrRokaH6Kzyll8SlVJDFZYUFFJQ6G07UVZwzSg7iK61dkcjJBHNOCcPeXPjHgP0bvS0cl9cJbhH3@6OANSSbcKgi80hKyiBuFPZSO79vjWd@zyDQ)</s>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcqxDoIwFIXhvU9xpE06GL0ye3GT1QcwGFqktgN1KAOB@OyVKMv5kpN/Tj5f4MCsr7daC7kjGyLN622qltWpha1UeWZmtUhDdH8o23zyGovOD@8n9hOcEEdyOPxWL/pvudlskgYkRh8SBjN2vk8oqEgIEcn31sRX/gI)

Both programs are independent (they don't read each other's source). I found the best way to tackle the challenge was to make two self-counting programs with the same character counts.  Using assignment to expand the simple `${#${$(<&0)//[^$1]}}` feels cheap, so do take a look at my older programs.

(*My second attempt hits a fork limit on TIO, so its TIO link uses a modified version that uses the non-forking `echo` instead of `<<<`.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>106</s> <s>100</s></sup> 96 bytes

Saved 10 bytes thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)!!!

```python
import inspect
f=lambda c:inspect.getsource(g).count(c)
g=lambda c:inspect.getsource(f).count(c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/BSgMxEIbveYohl2StFrSCUJge24ewIuuYpMFuEpLJQZZ99u1ai64X6e1n@D@@f9InH2JYjaPvUswMPpRkiIXFY9u9vbdA68tp6QyXWDMZ7ZolxRpYUyPcf0X7Wxxtjh0Uzj44@JbdiC3Ka0VS7FBeK5OCDoY@TEat9vXh6ZHU7Tncr1QjbMxA06fQFvL@9WiYTS6LVANxbdnHsBZQAMF@PQg8JXdOaRrP2iqrZU@DbOBuA30ZoL/Yngvi7mfEy6BmjJszPGMYcfuHGU8)

Two mutually dependent lambdas that simply read each other's source code and return the input character count.

Comment: I suppose there's a good reason, but why don't you just do [this](https://tio.run/##jY/LCsIwEEX3@YohmyT4AB8gCONSP0Jd1DFJi9qUJAW19NtrLaJ1I@4Ow33MLW4xdfmsabJL4XyELA@FpsgMnpPL4ZgALV@nsdUxuNKTllaNyZV5lKSY/SU0H2GzRv5vKGcb5P8Gc0apppP2KMWunC7mJIYdTGZCMeM8XNtV4JPcaun8UYpEqGEHd6EGE7VkQIBAqZdXxSC0bJ7LILZkOyp81nYZYSSvqOYKRiuoQg3Vq3obEDfvj/a16Hls3xN7noi4/vI0Dw)?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Not allowed to be the same function, does a different variable name count? I took it more in the spirit than to the letter! :)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Having re-read the OP, it does say: *which must not be identical programs*. So it's allowed since they're not *identical* - thanks! :D

Comment: Sorry, but disqualified by the new rule. They are dependent, which is out by the new rule.

Comment: @Andrew You shouldn't change the rules like that after people have taken the time to answer your OP.

Comment: I apologize, but I was always going for the idea that the two lambdas were independent. I forgot to jot it until today, and this is the less damaging of the two rules I wanted as 7 out of 11 posts already have independent version.

Comment: @Andrew You should have stuck with what you originally posted, thinking of the people that took the time to answer rather than of yourself and what you wanted.

Comment: You were right.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>85</s> 63 bytes

```
p=k=>('q='+p).split(k).length-1
q=k=>('p='+q).split(k).length-1
```

Mutually independent functions (thanks to [user81655](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46855/)). Each function reads its own source code since the character counts are the same after the concatenation.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcpBCoAgEEDRvReZGcKgXRu7i0SUKTKj4vUnwW3Lz/uv776eJXCzfVdlF92BIA4WprVyCg0jrenKd3vsZmQ6D5cfVy4hN2SECERmlox/lH4)

Comment: I feel this answer is borderline, because the 2 functions have to be in the same program fo it to work. I reckon this is not explicitly stated in the question that each program cannot read the other's source code, but it explicitly asked for 2 separate programs

Comment: @Kaddath Same would apply to [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220093/43319).

Comment: @Adám I don't know APL enough, I thought in yours each function read its own source code and replaced the letter, and not each other's code

Comment: @Kaddath No, they do read each others' code, but your method might be viable should OP ever decide to prohibit reading each other.

Comment: This solution can be trivially modified to not read each other's code with
`p=k=>('q='+p).split(k).length-1` and `q=k=>('p='+q).split(k).length-1`.
The character counts happen to be correct if you make each function read itself.

Comment: @user81655 Good idea!

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
Ｉ⊗№⁺´”´””yＩ⊗№⁺´´yＳ”Ｓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npWPuqY/apn2qHHXoS2PGuaCCSCqRJU5tAUosBkoDiT//z@0BQA)

```
Ｉ⊗№⁺”yＩ⊗№⁺´´yＳ”´”´”Ｓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npWPuqY/apn2qHHXo4a5lcj8Q1sObQEKbAaKH9oCI4D8//8PbQEA)

The first program is simply my answer to [Counting characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205163/) and the second is a trivial rearrangement.